# Laravel, include foreach result in many functions in controller

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store the foreach of Cart somewhere like in model and retrive it in many controller functions, so is this possible

```
public function deleteProducts($rowId)
  {
Cart::remove($rowId);


$products = Cart::content();

  //Here what I want to retrive without writing this code many times

 foreach($products as $Product){
echo '<div class="OrderItem_root styles_base styles_spacing-base">
 <div class="OrderItem_quantity styles_just-right styles_base styles_spacing-base">'.$Product->qty.'</div>
  <div class="OrderItem_container">
    <div class="OrderItem_category"></div>
  <div class="OrderItem_itemHeader">
    <div id="titletest" class="OrderItem_name styles_just-right styles_base styles_spacing-base">'.$Product->name.'</div>
 <div id="cartprice" class="OrderItem_total">$'.$Product->price*$Product->qty.'</div>
    <input id="mycartprice" type="text" name="mycartprice" value="'.$Product->price.'"  hidden="">
 </div>
  <div>
</div>
  <div>
     <input id="mycart" type="text" name="mycartprice" value="'.Cart::subtotal().'"  hidden="">

   <button class="remove_item OrderItem_action Button_root" data-id="'.$Product->rowId.'" data-price="'.$Product->price*$Product->qty.'" data-qty="'.$Product->qty.'" type="submit">Remove</button>

  </div>
   </div>
    </div>';
  }   
   }
```

Comment: If at all possible, don't do this in a controller. You can instead create a view and return that, or save it to a variable. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views

Comment: hope you can help me in this, because im using ajax to return data, and yes I dont want to write html in cotroller but dont know how to return forloop in ajax

Comment: Don't do it in Ajax. As I said, create a view, and pass the products to the view. Use the view to create the HTML with the loop. Then return the view to the Ajax, which can then insert it wherever you want. I can't write out the code for you, but that should help you get started.

Comment: unfortunately, I cant understand you, where I have to create view? I dont want to reload the page after add or delete from Cart!! is there any small example about what you say? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the html with a function of your Product model (call that function *showOrder*, for example) instead of your controller, then you can do

```
foreach($products as $Product){
   echo $Product->showOrder();
}
```

Comment: can you explain more, where to write the function showOrder?

Comment: Depends. Does Cart::content(); return a collection of a certain model (e.g. App\Product)? then you do it in your Product model.

Comment: the proplem is this is  not possible as any model

Comment: You can always create a new model with just a static function that you pass the product to as variable, and returns you your html. you'd call it like this: echo App\HelperModel::myStaticFunction($Product);

Comment: Im new to laravel so I dont know exactly how to write or where to write it

Comment: It is difficult to explain these things if you do not have basic Laravel knowledge. I suggest you read up on documentation first https://laravel.com/docs/5.8 to see where to put models, controllers, views, and how to use them. Things will become much clearer then, and you will be able to find your own solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196645/discussion-between-ash-and-mrevers).